# How this ansible run with regex

Tags: ansible

Can somebody please explain for me about this code:

- What is the loop_var function
- what will be returned as regex.path, regex.regex and regex.replace

```
block:
  - name: Replace text on file
    replace:
      path: "{{APP_HOME}}/{{ALIAS_NAME}}/{{regex.path}}"
      regexp: "{{regex.regex}}"
      replace: "{{regex.replace}}"
    with_items: "{{APP_REPLACE}}"
    loop_control:
       loop_var: regex
```

Comment: Have you read the [relevant Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var)?

Comment: Yes, I read it, but I can not clearly understand what the loop_var will return

Comment: It doesn't "return" anything. It changes the name of the loop variable from `item` to whatever you choose.

Comment: oh, you mean it just changes the value of the var=regex to another value with every value of item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be clear to you if you rename the `loop_var`:

```
- name: Replace text on file
  replace:
    path: "{{APP_HOME}}/{{ALIAS_NAME}}/{{fred.path}}"
    regexp: "{{fred.regex}}"
    replace: "{{fred.replace}}"
  with_items: "{{APP_REPLACE}}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: fred
```

And try this:

```
- name: Show APP_REPLACE
  debug:
    var: APP_REPLACE
```

You'll see that each element of `APP_REPLACE` has three parts: `path`, `regex`, and `replace`.

Comment: Could you please give an example playbook to run with ansible for me to understand fully about this?

Comment: Well, no, since I don't have your `APP_REPLACE` definition.  Stick those two tasks in your playbook and see what you get.

Comment: The APP_REPLACE definition I posted below this comment with the variables file name is var.yml. Could you help me to give an example, just pretend the APP_NAME = MYAPP

Comment: Have you run those `debug` tasks I posted?  The answer is still "NO, I CAN'T. "  The reason that I cannot is that I do not have the structure of `MYAPP'`.  Is should have the elements `path`, `regex`, and `replace` defined.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining to me, I still have a question that cant understand. In the APP_REPLACE: "{{ SERVICE['replace'] | default('')  }}". What is the function of "['replace']". What dose it do in this structure.

Comment: @TRONGNGUYEN It's just an ugly way of writing `SERVICE.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

vars.yml

```
APP_NAME: False
SERVICE: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME] | default('')}}"
APP_HOME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['app_home'] | default('') }}"
ALIAS_NAME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['alias_name'] | default(APP_NAME)  | default('') }}"
PROCESS_NAME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['process_name'] | default('') }}"
ORIGIN_PROCESS_NAME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['original_process_name'] | default(PROCESS_NAME)  | default('') }}"
JAVA_HOME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['java_home'] | default('')}}"
APP_REPLACE: "{{ SERVICE['replace'] | default('')  }}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).